# ssl cURL - convert terminal curl command to PHP script

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have this terminal curl command that works properly

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cert cert.p12:myPassword -X POST -d ‘myJsonData’ https://api-applecareconnect-ept.apple.com/enroll-service/1.0/bulk-enroll-devices

I have converted the command like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "cert.p12"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "P12"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "myPassword");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myJsonData);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);

    if(empty($ret)) { echo 'error: nothing returned'; } else { echo 'success!'; }

    echo $ret;
    if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
         $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
         echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

but I received the error “Access is Denied. Client SSL Certificate Required”.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For SSL_VERIFYHOST For '2' you have to ensure the common name in the SSL certificate matches the hostname being utilized. This is the default and should be straight-forward as long as your SSL certificate is appropriately created for the hostname (common name) you're using it on

Comment: SSL Certificate's creation is correct now because before I did it wrong and my curl request didn't work either in terminal and php. Now with the new certificate my curl request on terminal work correctly but in PHP nothing. What exactly should I do?